# Trigger "update" button in Wordpress post automatically

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm using the [Modern Events Calendar](https://webnus.net/modern-events-calendar/) plugin for Wordpress and I am pushing the events from one site to another site (not a multisite!) via the [Distributor](https://distributorplugin.com/) plugin. When pushing events the mec_events and mec_dates tables' database entries are not created till I manually hit the "update" button in the pushed event. As far as I get it said entries are pushed as post meta, and then converted to db entries on hitting the update button.

Or in other words: The update button of a event type post triggers stuff in the event plugin that I need to happen, and I'm unable to find out what exactly needs to happen, because the plugin is very complex. So my idea would be to find a way to actually push the update button to trigger everything I need BUT automatically. Dirty, I know, but seems to be the "easy way out" to me. The events are imported perfectly fine, and after manually using the update button in the event everything is correct. It's just that I don't want to have to do that every time manually for every event.

How can I trigger the same stuff that happens when manually using the update button, but via code / php?

(Obviously I already tried wp_update_post etc., pushing the event as draft and then publishing it via code, but none of those trigger the actions I need the event plugin to do, hence the creation of db entries from post meta. Only the dreaded big blue button does.)

EDIT1: Very simple example of what I tried would be this (after pushing the draft):

```
// Publish post 37
  $post = array(
      'ID'           => 37,
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
  );


// Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $post );
```

I assumed this (or wp_insert_post or save_post) would trigger all hooks of the update button, but to no avail.

EDIT2: After playing around with changing meta data using the following code I am now sure that wp_update_post doesn't trigger the needed actions.

```
function change_postmeta(){

       $args = array(
           'post_type'      => 'mec-events',
           'post_status'    => 'publish',
           'posts_per_page' => -1
       );
       $posts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach($posts as $p) :

        $meta = get_post_meta($p->ID, 'mec_start_date',true);

        echo "<script>console.log('POST IDs: " . json_encode($p->ID) . "');</script>";


        if($meta) :
            $my_post = array();
            $my_post['ID'] = $p->ID;
            $my_post['post_content'] = $meta . "works!"  . $p->post_content ;

            // Update the post into the database
            wp_update_post( $my_post );
            unset($my_post);

            //remove the meta key
            delete_post_meta($p->ID, 'mec_start_date');

        endif;

    endforeach;


}
```

Using this prints the event start date successfully to the content and saves it, but it doesn't trigger the same stuff that happens when doing a manual update of a post. And I still haven't found a way to find out what is actually tied to the blue button.

Comment: You likely need to do something like `do_action('save_post', $postID, $WP_Post)`. Do you have any code you've tried that we can look at?

Comment: Question updated - tried a lot of different ways to save or update the post, but none trigger the plugin's hooks I need.

Comment: You found any workarounds or anything?